# Golang - signal other goroutines to stop and return when one goroutine has found the result

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I would like to speed up a certain task in Go by starting several worker goroutines.

In the [example](http://play.golang.org/p/Jt9OnEbVHt) below, I'm looking for a "treasure". Worker goroutines that are started will dig forever for items until they are told to stop. If the item is a wanted treasure, then it is placed onto a shared buffered channel with a capacity equals to the number of workers.

The program is only interested in getting one treasure. It also has to make sure that all workers goroutines will return and not be blocked forever.

The example works, but is there a cleaner or more idiomatic way to ensuring the above?

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func digTreasure() int {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)
    return rand.Intn(1000)
}

func worker(i int, ch chan int, quit chan struct{}) {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("worker", i, "left")
        wg.Done()
    }()
    for {
        treasure := digTreasure()
        if treasure%100 == 0 {
            fmt.Println("worker", i, "found treasure", treasure)
            ch <- treasure
            return
        }

        select {
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("worker", i, "quitting")
            return
        default:
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    n := 10
    ch, quit := make(chan int, n), make(chan struct{})
    fmt.Println("Searching...")

    wg.Add(n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go worker(i, ch, quit)
    }
    fmt.Println("I found treasure:", <-ch)
    close(quit)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All workers left")
}
```

Comment: If you have the solution which works flawlessly, this question might be off-topic, and is better suited for [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @icza for pointing out codereview to me. I will check out the site.

Comment: In your real code, aren't the workers (`digTreasure()`) using some common input channel? Often this is the case and gives you a natural way of stopping routines.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/context

Comment: @tomaszm, the workers are already a common quit channel.

Comment: I found another way that uses an unbuffered channel. In a real example, that works better. See [example at Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2zQ6yRPIWL).